# How to avoid table drop when reinitalizing subscription (Replication)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, publish-subscribe

In replicated database I add extra column into each table. Every time I reinitialize subscription all tables are dropped and I loose column that I added so I have to add it again. Is it possible to avoid dropping table so that replication process uses existing data in db?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what type of replication you're using - is it snapshot, transactional, merge or peer-to-peer?

Regardless of the type the short answer to your question is no; in a replication snapshot, the schema of the table on the subscriber must match the publisher (or, to be accurate, the filtered column list from the article on the publisher included in the snapshot)

If the schemas do not match, attempts to apply the snapshot will fail.

There are a couple of ways around this:

If you need to keep information on the subscriber which links to rows on the publisher, the simplest way would be to store that information in another table on the subscriber with a column which links it to the primary key of the replicated table. Note that you won't be able to enforce this relationship with a foreign key, because doing so will prevent the table article on the subscriber being dropped or cleared down when a new snapshot is applied.

An alternative (and more complex) method would be to amend the publication to execute a pre-snapshot script which renamed the table on the subscriber and a post-snapshot script which created the new column, copied the data from the additional column on the renamed table to the newly created table, then dropped the renamed table. See the documentation for [`sp_addpublication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188738.aspx) for details (`@pre_snapshot_script` and `@post_snapshot_script` parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're wanting to add a column, you'll want to do this on the publication database and have it propagate to the subscriber(s) with the publication property **@replicate_ddl** set to true.  Reinitialization is not required.

You'll want to do this using *ALTER TABLE < Table  > ADD < Column >* syntax on the Publisher.

Have a look at [Making Schema Changes on Publication Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx).